# Get current logged user SID with no-admin account

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, security, sid

I am developing a C# app.

For the application to work, the user must launch the application with administrative rights.

So if a user with a no-admin account wants to launch the application, he must right click and choose "Run as another user" to authenticate with an administrator account.
The problem is that once logged in with the administrator account, I can’t get the no-admin user’s SID back.

When I’m doing this:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User
```

Its returns the SID of the admin user with which the user has logged in. However, I want to recover the SID of the user who logged in with the administrator account.

Comment: See some of the answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681358/get-current-user-name-when-starting-with-uac . I suspect you might end up launching as non-elevated, which then starts your actual process, as elevated, passing the original non-elevated user's SID.

Comment: Do users "Right click -> Run as administrator" or "Right click -> Run as different user"? If I understand correctly you are asking how to know the user executing the exe when "Run as different user" has been done. Am I right?

Comment: @bradbury9 Yes :)

Comment: have not tested, but you could try `Environment.UserName`. According to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36e1bcfa-a46a-47a8-8b21-78357efe866b/how-to-get-windows-login-credentials-using-cnet?forum=netfxbcl) it could be different from `GetCurrent()`

Comment: @canton7 Thank you :) I found the solution !

Comment: @DDbout You can answer your own question, it is even encouraged, so others with a similar problem would get to the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :)

I use [Cassia](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cassia/) to find the user name :

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
ITerminalServicesSession session = manager.CurrentSession;
```

And [select all users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-account) who match with `session.UserName` and `session.DomainName` :

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Account where Name='" + session.UserName + "' AND Domain='" + session.DomainName + "'");
ManagementObjectCollection Users = mos.Get();
```

And after [found the %appData% with user SID](https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/07/retrieve-appdata-folder-path.html) :

```
// Get first user
ManagementObject[] arr = new ManagementObject[1];
Users.CopyTo(arr, 0);
ManagementObject User = arr[0];

// Found the %appData%
const string regValueLocalAppData = @"AppData";
const string regKeyShellFolders = @"HKEY_USERS\$SID$\Software\Microsoft\Windows\" +
                                                  @"CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders";

var localAppDataPath = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(regKeyShellFolders.Replace("$SID$", User["SID"].ToString()), regValueLocalAppData, null) as string;

// Check if %appData% is not empty// Le dossier %appData% existe
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(localAppDataPath))
{
    PathToRoaming = localAppDataPath;
}
```

It is also possible to create the path and check if it exists :

```
public string GetAppdataPath() {
    string PathToRoaming = "";

    ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
    ITerminalServicesSession session = manager.CurrentSession;

    // Get path to Users directory
    Guid UserProfilesGuid = new Guid("0762D272-C50A-4BB0-A382-697DCD729B80");
    IntPtr pPath;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(UserProfilesGuid, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out pPath);
    string PathToUsers = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pPath);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pPath);

    // Build path
    string PathToRoamingDir = String.Format("{0}\\{1}\\AppData\\Roaming", PathToUsers, session.UserName);

   if (Directory.Exists(PathToRoamingDir))
   {
      PathToRoaming = PathToRoamingDir;
   }
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken, out IntPtr pszPath);
```